# Why is selenium not looping properly?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

I ran this code trying to scrape a dynamic website using selenium. instead of running a for loop as instructed by my code and giving me more data in the other elements that share the same class name. it repeats the first element's data only.

**Code**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

ser= Service("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,service=ser)
driver.get('https://soundcloud.com/jujubucks')
print(driver.title)

song_contents = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'soundList__item')


song_list = []

for song in song_contents:
 search = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'soundTitle__usernameText').text
 search_song = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[@class=""]').text
 search_date = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'sc-visuallyhidden').text
 search_plays = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="content"]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div/ul/li/span/span[2]').text
 song ={
     'Artist': search, 
     'Song_title': search_song, 
     'Date': search_date,
     'Streams': search_plays
 }

 song_list.append(song)

df = pd.DataFrame(song_list)
print(df)

driver.quit()
```

this is the output that it gives. only one set of data instead of moving on to other sets

**Output**

```
Stream Juju Bucks music | Listen to songs, albums, playlists for free on SoundCloud
       Artist                              Song_title               Date Streams
0  Juju Bucks  Squad Too Deep Ft. Cool Prince (Outro)  Posted 1 year ago      31
1  Juju Bucks  Squad Too Deep Ft. Cool Prince (Outro)  Posted 1 year ago      31
2  Juju Bucks  Squad Too Deep Ft. Cool Prince (Outro)  Posted 1 year ago      31
3  Juju Bucks  Squad Too Deep Ft. Cool Prince (Outro)  Posted 1 year ago      31
4  Juju Bucks  Squad Too Deep Ft. Cool Prince (Outro)  Posted 1 year ago      31
```

Comment: your locators are the same each iteration.   Maybe you wanted to do "song.find_element..."?  I would also avoid using "song" as an array... (probably isn't an issue, it's just messing with iterator variable... )  maybe use "song-info" instead?

Comment: shouldn't they be? all of the songs share the same element name or structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find element within in an element use a dot in the xpath like below:

```
driver.get("https://soundcloud.com/jujubucks")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

# Close Cookie pop-up
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()

song_contents = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'soundList__item')

for option in song_contents:
    title = option.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[contains(@class,'soundTitle__title')]/span").text # Extract title from that particular song.
    print(title)
```

**Update:**

```
i = 1
for _ in range(20):
    song_contents = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='soundList__item'][{}]".format(i))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",song_contents)
    title = song_contents.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[contains(@class,'soundTitle__title')]/span").text # Use a dot in the xpath to find element within in an element
    print(title)
    i+=1
```

```
Squad Too Deep Ft. Cool Prince (Outro)
Tropikana ft. P-Dogg Amazing
Party Ka Mngani Ft. X-Poll
Joy Ft. Black Sushi & Gavin Bowden
Amazing ft. X-Poll
Owami
Phakade
Ain't No Thang ft. Musiholiq
Bhalela Ft. X-Poll
Piece Of Me ft. King Cobra
Put Me Down ft. Fabee (Interlude)
Way Up ft. Musiholiq
Carlito ft. Captain Blu
Blaze
Talk About Me (Ft. Cool Prince)
Get Em Up
Ntate Modimo
In Bucks We Trust (Gold Edition)
Intro (In Bucks We Trust )
Juju Bucks - Show Me (ft. Mbali Zondi)
```

Comment: why is it only returning 5 titles instead of the whole catalogue?

Comment: @HoustonKhanyile - The songs appear as you scroll down. And the list gets updated respectively in the DOM. Apply scrolling effect.

Comment: @HoustonKhanyile - Have updated the answer. Go through the same. You can refer this like - [https://stackoverflow.com/q/69375160/16452840](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69375160/16452840)

Comment: this update has made it worse instead of iterating. it only gets back the first element. I've done my best trying to fix it but I cant.

Comment: @HoustonKhanyile - It worked fine for me. Have updated the output of the code. Not sure how you are applying the scroll.

Comment: you are right but the problem is I want to include other sets of data like date, plays and artist name just like in my above code. I was trying to incorporate ur code with mine and its not working. that's I'm having a problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238670/discussion-between-houston-khanyile-and-pmadhu).